# adding list as a sublist in a nested list at the start of the nested list Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, insertion

given a nested list:

```
input_list = [['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

addition_to_input_list = ['a', 'b']

required_output = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

for my current program, it is enough to put the addition at the start, in the future I may have to also put the addition at a specific index in the nested list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [list.insert(index, item)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Personally I like this syntax for this `[addition_to_input_list, *input_list]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple list insertion.  It doesn't matter that the elements are lists themselves.  So, this will do it:

```
input_list.insert( 0, addition_to_input_list )
```

Or you can build a new list:

```
required_output = [addition_to_input_list] + input_list
```

Proof that both options work:

```
>>> input_list = [['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>> addition_to_input_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> input_list.insert(0,addition_to_input_list)
>>> input_list
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

>>> input_list = [['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>> [addition_to_input_list]+input_list
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>>
```

Comment: Hey, when i do the above mentioned method, i get this as the output
current_output = ['a', 'b', ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
but i want the list ['a', 'b'] to be added as a sublist,
required_output  = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

Comment: Then you made a typo.  Both of my commands work exactly as they are presented.  I'm guessing you tried the second example but did not include the brackets around the first list.